# How to install ruby?

Tags: ruby, download, installation

I want to start learning ruby, but I don't know what kind of code editor to download,as I'm a beginner (GNU Compiler,windows 7 ,32 bits),can you give me a suggestion or a link,that doesn't contain viruses.
Thank you.

Comment: Too opinion based.

Comment: Try http://railsinstaller.org/en

Comment: @BlackBeard Don't encourage off-topic questions to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user202729 You are right. But, often beginners user find it hard to install Ruby-On-Rails on their Windows system.

Comment: [ruby installer](https://rubyinstaller.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, if you really wanna learn ruby ​​as well, it will be much easier and more correct to install linux (ubuntu), since most ruby-devs uses linux-distributions. With linux it will be easy to install ruby and rails. If you talk about IDE, i suggest JetBrains RubyMine for start.